# flutter image scale up and drag

Tags: flutter, dart, drag, gesturedetector

I receive a double variable called nZoom and set the scale of the image.
I have implemented pinch zoom and out using GestureDetector class and it is working fine. Of course, dragging after zoom-in also works fine.

Double-type nZoom receives a value by clicking the button. If you click the zoom in button, the size of nZoom increases, and if you click the zoom out button, nZoom decreases.

```
Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 170,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.zoom_in,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if(nZoom[0] < 2.0) nZoom[0] = nZoom[0] + 0.3;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 130,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.zoom_out,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if(nZoom[0] > 1.0) nZoom[0] = nZoom[0] - 0.3;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
```

I want to see the part off the screen by dragging after increasing the scale of the image by pressing the zoom button. I tried to use onPanUpdate, but it says it can't be used with onScaleUpdate.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart';

class SheetMusic extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<bool>? bFlag;
  double? nZoom;

  @override
  SheetMusic({this.bFlag, this.nZoom});

  @override
  _SheetMusicState createState() => _SheetMusicState();
}

class _SheetMusicState extends State<SheetMusic>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation? _animation;
  AnimationController? _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _animationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    _animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 2.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController!, curve: Curves.easeInOut))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  Offset offset = Offset.zero;

  final transController = TransformationController();
  TapDownDetails? doubleTapDetails;
  

  showMessage(String message, BuildContext context) {
    showMenu(
        context: context,
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(300, 300, 300, 300),
        items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text(
              message,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          )
        ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    double _scale = widget.nZoom!;
    double _previousScale = 1.0;

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: 60,
          left: 10,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) {
              print(details);
              _previousScale = 1.0;
              setState(() {});
            },
            onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
              print(details);
              _scale = _previousScale * details.scale;
              setState(() {});
            },
            onScaleEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) {
              print(details);
              _previousScale = 1.0;
              setState(() {});
            },
            
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: transController,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                width: size.width * 0.95,
                height: size.height * 0.7,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF42A5F5)),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  child: Transform(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    transform:
                        Matrix4.diagonal3(Vector3(_scale, _scale, _scale)),
                    child: !(widget.bFlag![0])
                        ? Image(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/3_total.png'),
                          )
                        : Image(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/all.png'),
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I checked the flutter docs, but couldn't find a way. Any good way?

I want to use onPanUpdate to use pinch zoom and drag together. I expected to do something like below, but it failed.

```
onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details){
              transController.value = Matrix4.identity()
                ..translate(offset.dx + details.delta.dx, offset.dy + details.delta.dy);           
              },
```

Comment: yes, you cannot use both `onPanUpdate` and `onScaleUpdate` - the latter can be used with `details.focalPoint` (or `focalPointDelta`)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the reply. I haven't received your reply. Can you give an example?

Comment: what fields did you want to use with `onPanUpdate` and its `DragUpdateDetails` parameter?

Comment: @pskink I want to use the child's Container field together.

Comment: you wanted to use `onPanUpdate`, right? if so it notifies you when panning with `DragUpdateDetails` variable, so what fields of that parameter did you want to use?

Comment: I think it's right to use the parameter delta.

Comment: so use `focalPointDelta` from `ScaleUpdateDetails`

Comment: Thank you. I know the intent of your answer. Following your advice, the problem was solved.